# MVC5: Delete Identity User results in Null Entry for Parameter ID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I have an administrator EDIT view created for USERS in my MVC5 application. Down in the bottom right I have a DELETE button that first asks the Admin logged in to confirm user deletion and then is supposed to execute the POST - Delete method in my UserManagement Controller. However when I confirm the deletion, I get an error of:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] Delete(Int32)' in 'PROJECT.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UserManagementController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

This is my delete button on the View:

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="width:180px; float: right; padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 7px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; ">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "UserManagement", new { id = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value="Delete User" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this User?');" />
    }
</div>
```

And this is the `[HttpPost]` of my `Delete` action:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (applicationUser == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to find User ID for deletion.");
        }
        else
        {
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(applicationUser);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserManagement");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to Delete User.");
                var errors = string.Join(",", result.Errors);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", errors);
            }
        }

        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```

Clearly somewhere I am failing to get the ID passed from the view to the Action, but I'm not quite sure how to resolve the issue. I'm still faily new to MVC development, let alone ASP.Net Identity. Any assistance appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I've tweaked my approach a little, but am still getting the same error. I have a Delete Confirmation View which loads the Delete() GET method. The View resembles the following:

```
@model PROJECT.Models.ApplicationUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
    string cancelEditUrl = "/Admin/UserManagement/";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this User?</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "UserManagement", new { id = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ForumUsername)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReceiveSystemEmails)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RegisteredDate)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LastVisitDate)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MemberOrgId)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProfilePictureSrc)

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Position)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Position, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Position)
            </div>
        </div>

  .....

   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1" style="padding-left: 0px">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9" style="padding-left: 0px">
            <a href="@cancelEditUrl" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
        </div>
   </div>

}
```

My Controller Actions for **Delete()**:

```
    //GET: Admin/UserManagement/Delete/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (applicationUser == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }

    // POST: Admin/UserManagement/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (applicationUser == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to find User ID for deletion.");
        }
        else
        {
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(applicationUser);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserManagement");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to Delete User.");
                var errors = string.Join(",", result.Errors);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", errors);
            }
        }

        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```

**ERROR**:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] Delete(Int32)' in 'PRISMdev.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UserManagementController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

I'm not quite sure why my Model ID is coming in as NULL still to the Delete() POST action.

Comment: Can you post the actual rendered HTML form?  It sounds like the id parameter is not actually being included in your form action URI.

Comment: I've attempted a new approach, but am getting basically the same error as before. See my EDIT.

Comment: The reason I asked for the *rendered* HTML output was to verify if you actually have a value in your `Id` property.  Can you post the rendered output so we can see exactly what your form looks like so we know what the HTTP request ends up looking like?

Comment: Thanks for replying Justin. I ended up just scrapping my approach and going with the standard switch to a Delete View for confirmation. To answer your question though, I added a `LabelFor` and `TextBoxFor` like with my other fields for the `ID` property and can confirm the property was indeed populated and NOT `Null`.